# Search common subgraph between two graphs

Tags: graph

I have two graphs G, H labeled  and I want to extract all common subgraph of two graphs, I got to a part that is:

1 - extract all the nodes that are in common, but I'm stuck on the part that includes:

2 - Step 1: Take the First vertex and store it in a set P = {first element}  (which will be the set of all common subgraph), and go to 2nd if it is adjacent to the first of the two P graph G and H, we add it, and so on, but I do not know how to do it when i  have more than 2

Comment: This is more promising! Now, post the code that you have so far, and you might get answers this time. :)

Comment: I am not sure but I think that this is an NP problem.

Comment: You've asked the same question six times now when you should have just edited the original to provide more details.  This is a huge waste of everyone's time.  Please review the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page before posting again.

Answer (score 2):

That is a NP-complete problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem